# PHP AJAX form returning entire webpage html as data

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a custom wordpress plugin that is using jquery and ajax to display errors and such without reloading the page.  Currently the data being returned by the ajax is the entire page's html code as a string.

I'll include only the relevant pieces:

```
<form id="contactForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="' . esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) . '" method="post"></form>
```

and the php:

```
// if the submit button is clicked, send the email
    if ( isset( $_POST['cf-submitted'] ) ) {
        $error = False;

        if (empty($_POST["cf-name"])){
            $nameError = "Name is required";
        } else {
            $name = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-name"] );
        }

          // sanitize form values
        $name = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-name"] );
        $email = sanitize_email( $_POST["cf-email"] );
        $phone = "Phone: " . sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-phone"] );
        $company = "Company: " . sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-company"] );
        $deliverablesArr = $_POST["formDeliverables"];
        $deliverables = "Deliverables: " . implode( $deliverablesArr);
        $body = "Message Body: " . esc_textarea( $_POST["cf-body"] );
```

...etc. etc.

```
    // If email has been process for sending, display a success message
    if ( !$error ) {
        if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments ) ) {
        echo '<div>';
        echo '<p>Thanks for contacting us, expect a response soon.</p>';
        echo '</div>';
            if ($attachmentSet) {
                print_r('attachment set');
                //clean up your temp files after sending
                foreach($attachments as $att) {
                    @unlink($att);
                };
            }
        } else {
            echo 'An unexpected error occurred';
        }
    }
```

and the javascript:

```
// Set up an event listener for the contact form.
$(function() {
    // Get the form.
    var form = $('#contactForm');

    // Get the messages div.
    var formMessages = $('#messages');

    $('#contactForm').submit(function(e) {
    // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
    e.preventDefault();

    // Serialize the form data.
    var formData = $(form).serialize();
    // Submit the form using AJAX.
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        data: formData
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
        $(formMessages).addClass('success');

        // Set the message text.
        $(formMessages).text(response);

        // Clear the form.
        $('#name').val('');
        $('#company').val('');
        $('#phone').val('');
        $('#email').val('');
        $('#projectDescription').val('');
    })
    .fail(function(data) {
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
        $(formMessages).addClass('error');

        // Set the message text.
        if (data.responseText !== '') {
            $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
        } else {
            $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
        }
    });
});
});
```

Not sure what is happening exactly here.  All the formData is serialized correctly and I can console.log that.  Something is happening in the ajax function that isn't agreeing with what I have. Have also tried explicitly setting which data is being used in the ajax call but it then it returns nothing at all. Just an empty string.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you seeing a full webpage?

Comment: It displays as the message. It is returned as a string but it's the code for that entire page.

Comment: Is the PHP your Ajax is running in the same file as the HTML?

Comment: Yes. It's a plugin set up so I have it all in the same file as separate functions.

Comment: This is the expected behavior. AJAX makes an *HTTP* request and unless you specify a different type of return data (`dataType` - see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/, the section on `dataType`).  What were you expecting to return?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have changed my dataType to json and still am returning the entire webpage's code as response text.  I am getting a 200 error code but can't tell why.

Comment: You should only return the JSON. If your script to create the JSON is in a web page you should isolate the code so it can run without all of that.